# onmouseover change image smoothly

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image switching with another one when hovering with mouse, it works well, but I want to make it change smoothly.

Here's my code :

```html
<img src="/images/doubleimgindex.png" class="w-100" 
     onmouseover="this.src='/images/doubleimgindex2.png'" 
     onmouseleave="this.src='/images/doubleimgindex.png'" />
```

I can't use div for this purpose, that's why I'm asking for help, is it possible?

Comment: Consider using CSS instead? Also, what do you mean by "change smoothly"? Do you mean fading between images?

Comment: yes, fading between images.

Comment: the problem is and will always be, on the first time one of your users visits the site those images have to be loaded from a server on-mouse-over, because they are not loaded before. That given, it will never be as smooth as loading (but hiding them) and then make a smooth transition

Comment: "can't use div for this purpose", why not? Is it possble? Yes.

Comment: I tried with css using content:url(), but css transitions don't seem to work with this usage

Comment: @evolutionxbox i'm very bad at using html/css, and when using a div, it doesn't appear as expected, and I want the image to be "stealable"

Comment: @caramba, you can preload the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fade between the images, you need to have two images on top of each other and fadein/out the upper one:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.upper-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.upper-image:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/400/300">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/400/300" class="upper-image">
</div>
```

In Action: https://codepen.io/theshark/pen/rNVVeLO

The fading can be done completely in css as seen in the example :)

The upper image is positioned on top of the lower image via position absolute and completely transparent. On hover the image opacity is scaled to 1 and the image fades in.

If you have further questions about the code, please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Nice answer. If you can't guarantee that the images are the same size, you may want to use a CSS background with `background-size: cover` for the top image, rather than an `img` tag.

Comment: @Rafi in my case, I don't need to check for that, my images are same size (it's actually one image over and above switching position when hovering) ; but in more general case it could be useful yes

Comment: @Rafi Think of this implementation as minimal Example. If the images are different sizes, it makes more sense to define the size of the container and work with cover.
Depending on the requierements that can be implemented with backround images and background-positon or with object-fit and normal img tags :)